# Witholding pay after verbal agreement made

Tags: salary

My daughter was hired by a man in the entertainment business to be his assistant in a foreign country for app. one month. He paid for the flight and she was to receive $800 a week. He had asked her to do a second job in another foreign country, which she initially agreed to, but after speaking to people about her safety in the country, was advised it would not be a good place for a young girl from America to be without bodyguards. She told the employer more than a month ahead of time, while they were in the first job location, that she could not do the second job. There was never a written contract for either job, only verbal. Now, the employer has told her she owes him the money he will be out for the airline ticket, training and loss of pay for whoever he gets to replace her and gave her the list of charges, showing that out of the $2400 she should be getting for her months work, she will receive only $235.00. They are in the foreign country at this time and have two weeks to go, she has no money as he has only given her money for food, not the weekly wage. She agreed to give him back the cost of the plane ticket as he told her - but did not show her the ticket, that it was already purchased. Is there something we can do?  Is this against any labor law?

Comment: Hello Mystic, and welcome to the Workplace! While we are all here to help, we are not lawyers, and our advice would be no substitute for proper legal advice. Legal questions are [off-topic here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You should consult a lawyer who has experience with that country's labor laws to see if those were violated, and one who is familiar with employment contracts in the state you are in to see what (if anything) you can do.

Comment: On a side note, it probably isn't the best idea to go overseas with someone without an employment contract and without having looked in to things such as safety beforehand. Regardless of what the law says her rights to payment are, if your daughter is in a dangerous country with no money and no means of returning, you may want to worry about that first.

Comment: @Mystic1101 - Sounds like you should send your daughter some money as quickly as possible to get out of her current situation. **This person does not sounds like somebody I would not trust.**  This type of behavior indicates this man is not 100% legit.  If thats the case he is unlikely going to come after your daughter for money, because his excuse, is complete and total non-sense.  You can get your money back from an airline ticket a month in advanced.  Even if this was days before the flight, they would credit his account, which can be used in future travels.

Comment: First, get your daughter out of there. Second, depending on the countries involved (yours and the foreign one) and the age of your daughter, you may want to consider getting the police involved. Also if your daughter is being charged for a ticket, get the employer to hand over the ticket.

Answer (score 10):

So, she went to a foreign country on a short-term job with no formal contract, to a place she should have bodyguards, and you now can't get the ticket to return her home?

You need to either get the money to buy a ticket to her now (onto her plastic etc), or get a ticket and fly out with it yourself.  You will never see that bought ticket, and may never see your daughter again.

Do it NOW, don't wait, worry about labour laws later once everyone is home and safe.

Comment: The country that she's in now is not dangerous, the next one will be. Nevertheless, your advice to pull out ASAP holds - a person who resorts to blackmail cannot be trusted.

Comment: As she's only getting "money for food" it sounds like her accommodation is tied to her employer. Whether or not the country as a whole is safe, that is a very vulnerable situation to be in. Coupled with the inability to get home, the threat of not having a roof over your head could be used for further coercion.